# Differentiate variables having null and 0

Tags: php

I have a variable which can have either a null or 0 as returned by `array_search` function in php

eg

```
Array ( [0] => 71 [1] => 75 [2] => 77 ) 

  $key = array_search(70, $array); // returns null

  $key = array_search(71, $array); // returns 0
```

But neither `is_null,isset` have any effect .....

Answer (score 7):

Use === operator

```
if ($key === null)
```

or

```
if ($key === 0)
```

Comment: +1 for the answer .... But is_numeric($key) solved the problem.... Dont know if its the wright way to do it....

Answer (score 3):

`if ($key === null)`

Should get the job done

Answer (score 1):

Try with **in_array** also like

```
if (in_array("my_val", $array)) {
    echo "Got It";
}
else{
    echo "Not found";
}
```

or from array_search you can check like

```
if(array_search(70, $array) === null)
     echo "Not Found";
if(array_search(70, $array) === 0)
     echo "Got it";
```